# Error installing R packages: permission denied [R]

Tags: r

I recently updated both R (4.0.2) and RStudio (1.3.1073) installations on my computer (Windows 8.1 64bit).

Then, I ran some old code and get a problem when loading the `RecordLinkage` package:

> package ‘ffbase’ could not be loaded

I saw that the `RecordLinkage` package depends on `ffbase` and `ff` package. The former is ok, but when try to (re)install `ff` I get a message that some file could not be opened.

> Error in install.packages : não foi possível abrir o arquivo 'C:/Users/vinicius.lima/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/file1e88630e7640/ff/doc/ANNOUNCEMENT-2.0.txt': Permission denied

The same type of message is given when I try to reinstall some packages like `RecordLinkage` itself and `tidyverse`, for example.

I *do not* have trouble installing the package `ISLR`, for example.

There are plenty of suggestions in other similar questions like:

- Checking admin permission
- Checking/changing the content of `.libPaths()´ function
- Changing to a machine user installation instead of an admin one ([description here](https://rpubs.com/tomhopper/windows_nonadmin_install))

None of these options worked for me.

I actually don't know if the recent update has anything to do with this, but it was the only significant change made in the last three weeks. Everything worked pretty fine before this.

I really appreciate if anybody can help with this.

Vinicius

Answer (score 0):

[Was having the same problem, could not figure it out for the life of me. I'm answering here also to hear about a better solution, whenever it appears. Seems to be an issue with package versions (my problems were with `ff`, `ffbase` and `bit`, btw)]

What I did as a workaround (as people with tight deadlines often do) to get back running with `RecordLinkage` work was install the following versions of packages:

`bit`: 1.1-14 
`ff`: 2.2-14 
`ffbase`: 0.12.7 
`RecordLinkage`: 0.4-11

got me back to work, hope it helps you out, too.